# Populate input fields from axios response reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have simple fields. I want to populate the input boxes based on the data that I get from axios response. See below image

[image]

I am using hooks, to save data to state.
My question is how I am able to populate input boxes upon clicking get details button (response from api).

see below codes

```
const [data, setData] = useState([])
const [advisoryDetails, setadvisoryDetails] = useState({
    ADVISORYID: '',
    ADVISORYDESC: '',
    CREATEDBY:'',
    MODIFIEDBY:'',
    STATUS1: ''        
})
const [advisoryDetails1, setadvisoryDetails1] = useState([])
const [advisoryID, setadvisoryID] = useState('')

const getAdvisoryTest = async () => {
    await axios.post('/API',advisoryID)
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data)
        setData(response.data)
        console.log('data',data)
        setadvisoryDetails1(response.data)
        console.log('advisoryDetails1',advisoryDetails1)
        alert('success')
    })

advisoryDetails1.map(adv => {
        advisoryDetails.ADVISORYID = adv.ADVISORYID;
        advisoryDetails.ADVISORYDESC = adv.ADVISORYDESC;
        advisoryDetails.CREATEDBY = adv.CREATEDBY;
        advisoryDetails.MODIFIEDBY = adv.MODIFIEDBY;
        if(adv.CREATEDBY && adv.MODIFIEDBY != '')
        {
            advisoryDetails.STATUS1 = 'Modified'
        }
        else{ advisoryDetails.STATUS1 = 'New'}

        console.log('populate',advisoryDetails)
    })
}
const txtAdvIdOnChange = e =>{
    setadvisoryID(prevState =>({
        ...prevState,
        'ADVISORYID':e.target.value
    }));
    console.log('onChange ID:',advisoryID)
}
return(
    <div>
        <label>AdvisoryID: </label>
        <input type='text' placeholder='Advisory ID' className='txtAdvisoryID' onChange={txtAdvIdOnChange} />
<button onClick={()=>getAdvisoryTest()}>Get Details</button>
        <br /><br />
<label>Advisory Desc: </label>
        <input type='text' placeholder='textbox1' className='txtAdvisoryDesc' value={advisoryDetails&&advisoryDetails.ADVISORYDESC} disabled/>
        <br/>
        <label>New / Modified: </label>
        <input type='text' placeholder='textbox2' className='txtStatus' value={advisoryDetails&&advisoryDetails.STATUS1} disabled/>
</div>)
```

On those codes input boxes was not populated, even in console.log
Hope you can help me thank you.

Comment: Why do you have `advisoryDetails.STATUS1 = 'Modified'`? Use `setadvisoryDetails` to update state like so: `setadvisoryDetails(prevState => ({...prevState, STATUS1: "Modified"}))`

Comment: And You know that since you're going through the array `advisoryDetails1`, it's only overriding the data to `advisoryDetails` and you'll see the last iteration's values

Comment: @HaseebA oh yes hehe my bad. But I still have problem populating input boxes upon clicking get details button

Comment: If you're setting `response.data` to `advisoryDetails1` Why not do use response's data to update it because its possible `advisoryDetails1` is not updated at that point.
```
const respData = response.data;
if (respData.length > 0) {
  const adv = respData[respData.length-1];
  setadvisoryDetails((prevState) => ({
    ...prevState,
    ...adv,
    STATUS1: adv.CREATEDBY && adv.MODIFIEDBY != '' ? 'Modified' : 'New'
  }))
}
```

Comment: Hi @HaseebA, can you post your answer so I can tagged it as the correct answer? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can refactor your code like below.
I've moved set `setadvisoryDetails` to within `.then()` of `axios` because you're using the same data and you're don't have to go through the loop if you just want the last iteration's value. And in the inputs you don't have to check if `advisoryDetails` exists or has non empty value because you've initialized it in `const [advisoryDetails, setadvisoryDetails] = useState({...})`

```
const App = (props) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([])
  const [advisoryDetails, setadvisoryDetails] = useState({
    ADVISORYID: '',
    ADVISORYDESC: '',
    CREATEDBY: '',
    MODIFIEDBY: '',
    STATUS1: ''
  })
  const [advisoryDetails1, setadvisoryDetails1] = useState([])
  const [advisoryID, setadvisoryID] = useState('')

  const getAdvisoryTest = () => {
    axios.post('/API', advisoryID)
      .then(response => {
        const respData = response.data;
        setData(respData)
        setadvisoryDetails1(respData)

        console.log({
          respData, data, advisoryDetails1
        });

        alert('success');

        if (respData.length > 0) {
          const adv = respData[respData.length - 1];
          setadvisoryDetails((prevState) => ({
            ...prevState,
            ...adv,
            STATUS1: adv.CREATEDBY && adv.MODIFIEDBY != '' ? 'Modified' : 'New'
          }))
        }

      })
  }

  const txtAdvIdOnChange = e => {
    setadvisoryID(prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      'ADVISORYID': e.target.value
    }));
    console.log('onChange ID:', advisoryID)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <label>AdvisoryID: </label>
      <input type='text' placeholder='Advisory ID' className='txtAdvisoryID' onChange={txtAdvIdOnChange} />
      {/* If you're just passing a function without any param or event params, then just pass the function name like a variable */}
      <button onClick={getAdvisoryTest}>Get Details</button>
      <br /><br />
      <label>Advisory Desc: </label>
      <input type='text' placeholder='textbox1' className='txtAdvisoryDesc' value={advisoryDetails.ADVISORYDESC} disabled />
      <br />
      <label>New / Modified: </label>
      <input type='text' placeholder='textbox2' className='txtStatus' value={advisoryDetails.STATUS1} disabled />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

when you click the get details button your state was not updating that was the issue(value only change when the state was updated otherwise it is not updated)

```
//before don't do like this 
advisoryDetails1.map(adv => {
        advisoryDetails.ADVISORYID = adv.ADVISORYID;
        advisoryDetails.ADVISORYDESC = adv.ADVISORYDESC;
        advisoryDetails.CREATEDBY = adv.CREATEDBY;
        advisoryDetails.MODIFIEDBY = adv.MODIFIEDBY;
        if(adv.CREATEDBY && adv.MODIFIEDBY != '')
        {
            advisoryDetails.STATUS1 = 'Modified'
        }
        else{ advisoryDetails.STATUS1 = 'New'}

        console.log('populate',advisoryDetails)
    })





//after(only last element of advisoryDetails1 array was updated in the state)
 advisoryDetails1.forEach(adv => {
    let STATUS1 ='New'
    if(adv.CREATEDBY && adv.MODIFIEDBY != '')
    {
        STATUS1  = 'Modified'
    }
   
     setadvisoryDetails({ADVISORYID : adv.ADVISORYID,
        ADVISORYDESC:adv.ADVISORYDESC,
        CREATEDBY:adv.CREATEDBY,
        MODIFIEDBY:adv.MODIFIEDBY,
       STATUS1:STATUS1 
     })
   })
```

if you want to view your last element in your advisoryDetails1 array do like this

```
 let adv=advisoryDetails1[advisoryDetails1.length -1];
    let STATUS1 ='New'
    if(adv.CREATEDBY && adv.MODIFIEDBY != '')
    {
        STATUS1  = 'Modified'
    }
   
     setadvisoryDetails({ADVISORYID : adv.ADVISORYID,
        ADVISORYDESC:adv.ADVISORYDESC,
        CREATEDBY:adv.CREATEDBY,
        MODIFIEDBY:adv.MODIFIEDBY,
        STATUS1:STATUS1 
     })
 


 //it update your advisoryDetails state when advisoryDetails1 changed
  useEffect(()=>{
    advisoryDetails1.forEach(adv => {
    let STATUS1 ='New'
    if(adv.CREATEDBY && adv.MODIFIEDBY != '')
    {
        STATUS1  = 'Modified'
    }
   
     setadvisoryDetails({ADVISORYID : adv.ADVISORYID,
        ADVISORYDESC:adv.ADVISORYDESC,
        CREATEDBY:adv.CREATEDBY,
        MODIFIEDBY:adv.MODIFIEDBY,
       STATUS1:STATUS1 
     })
   })
  },[advisoryDetails1]);
//check whether advisoryDetails is changed or not 
      useEffect(()=>{
        console.log('populate',advisoryDetails)
      },[advisoryDetails])
```

everything fine but doesn't do like this only the last element of the array was updated so you must need some changes based on your requirements

Comment: hi @baskaran-ajiharan, upon using your 2nd set of codes the one under //after comment. advisoryDetails is not yet populated with the data on first click (i checked it thru console.log). I want to populate the advisoryDetails right after I clicked the button, for me to use it and populate the input boxes right away. Thank you

Comment: And I make sure that the axios response, only returns one set of data.

Comment: I just update my answer can you recheck again &you can't check with the console.log statement directly because it is asynchronous. you can only check with the render method or useEffect hook. if your data has only one set then return as object don't return as an array in the backend

Answer (score 0):

On your input value properties try adding a space either side of the `&&`.

```
<input type='text' placeholder='textbox2' className='txtStatus' value={advisoryDetails.STATUS1 && advisoryDetails.STATUS1} disabled/>
```

Comment: still getting same issue.